# How to write xml.etree._Element to a file in python?

Tags: python, xml

I have an element of a tree that I want to write to a file, but you can only write strings to a file and I can't seem to convert it to a string. I tried the following:

```py
elem = tree.find('Element', {})
file = open(filepath, "w+")
file.write(prod.text)
file.close()
```

Which gives the following error:
`TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None` even though elem is not None

My other approach was:

```py
elem = tree.find('Element', {})
prod.write(filepath, pretty_print=True)
file.close()
```

Which gave: `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'write'`

Any ideas how to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem. `.text` is only for the text within tags but since element consists of a lot of other tags, this doesn't make sense. The function`etree_lxml.tostring(element)` converts the element to a string. It also has the optional argument `pretty_print=True` for those interested in a more readable result. So the following code now works:

```py
from lxml import etree 

elem = tree.find('Element', {})
file = open(filepath, "wb+")
file.write(etree.tostring(element))
file.close()
```